# Group Theory and Divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is the problem I'm working at:

> Find a divisor $d$ of $6! = 720$ such that $S_6$ does not have a subgroup of order $d$.

**Initial Approach**: 
So I factored the number $720$ and here are the divisors that I came up with:

$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 45, 48, 60, 72, 80, 90, 120, 144, 180, 240, 360, 720$

So there are a total of 30 divisors for the number $720$. I believe it would be helpful to know *how many* total subgroups are there in $S_6$. I did find [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group:S6) link, not sure if it would help out or not.

**Update**

So after doing some further research, I found out that $S_6$ has a total of $1455$ subgroups, but a proof is not given as to why this is true. But why is this true? Well the divisors of $1455$ are given as follows:

$1, 3, 5, 15, 97, 291, 485, 1455$

Comment: I doubt the total number of subgroups will help. Perhaps you could try going in the other direction -- can you make a list of divisors of $720$ that *do* show up as orders of subgroups $S_6$? Symmetric groups, alternating groups, cyclic groups, etc. I personally suspect *large* orders (like $720/3 = 240$) are less likely to show up.

Comment: Ah well, in that case, I believe this calls for [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) then. Right?

Comment: You can show that $S_6$ has subgroups of order $2,3,4,5,6,12,24,60,120,360,720$ by using the fact that every symmetric group has an alternating group inside, and using Cauchy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see how knowing the number of subgroups in $S_{6}$ really helps, but here is an argument which may help, provided you know the classification of groups of order $pq$ for distinct primes $p, q$. Note that any group of order $15$ must be cyclic, since $15$ is the product of the distinct primes $3$ and $5$, and $5$ is not congruent to $1$ mod $3$. Hence, if $S_{6}$ had a subgroup of order $15$, it must have an element of order $15$. But this cannot be, since the order of any element of $S_{6}$ is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles in its disjoint cycle decomposition.

Comment: *Much* simpler than I was thinking. Well done!

Comment: Yes I just got done reading the proof. Definitely a (+1).

Comment: @pjs36: thanks! I had no idea what else to try, but happily this approach worked.